# Idris "did not change type" for rewrite with exact same type

Tags: proof, idris

**Context** I'm trying to write a version of `++` for `Vect` where the compiler can infer the resulting `Vect` has the expected contents.

**Detail** I'm struggling to see why this second rewrite isn't working

```
import Data.Vect
import Data.Nat

infixl 9 ++:

public export
(++:) : {0 r, r' : Nat} -> Vect r Nat -> Vect r' Nat -> Vect (r' + r) Nat
(++:) [] y = rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral r' in y
(++:) {r = S rr} (x :: xs) y = rewrite plusSuccRightSucc r' rr in x :: (xs ++: y)
```

I've intentionally added the vector lengths in the signature in the reverse order to make the API easier to use. I'm seeing

```
"tmp.idr" 8L, 254C written
Error: While processing right hand side of ++:. Rewriting by S (r' + rr) = r' + S rr did not change type Vect (r' + S rr) Nat.

/src/tmp.idr:8:32--8:82
   |
 8 | (++:) {r = S rr} (x :: xs) y = rewrite plusSuccRightSucc r' rr in x :: (xs ++: y)
```

I don't get why a proof that `r' + S rr` is equal to `S (r' + rr)` doesn't rewrite `r' + S rr`. Here's the error when I don't have the rewrite

```
"tmp.idr" 8L, 219C written
Error: While processing right hand side of ++:. Can't solve constraint between: S (plus r' rr) and plus r' (S rr).

/src/tmp.idr:8:32--8:47
   |
 8 | (++:) {r = S rr} (x :: xs) y = x :: (xs ++: y)
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple because `rewrite` works in the reverse order. So if the goal is `goal` but you have `a`, you need a proof `goal = a`, not `a = goal`. (I found this always very confusing, as the `replace` in the background takes `a = goal`, but I guess it is because `rewrite` rewrites the goal term.)  So with `sym` this should work:

```
(++:) {r = S rr} (x :: xs) y = rewrite sym $ plusSuccRightSucc r' rr in x :: (xs ++: y)
```