# Idris: rewrite does not work (rewriting by ... did not change)

Tags: idris

I'm proving a theorem in Idris, and in the 2nd case:

```
theorem1 t1 t2 s (S_Trans u hyp1 hyp2) = let 
    (s1 ** (s2 ** (ueq, st1, st2))) = theorem1 t1 t2 u 
    hyp1' = rewrite ueq in hyp1
    in case theorem1 s1 s2 s hyp1' of
        (s1' ** (s2' ** (ueq', st1', st2'))) => (s1' ** (s2' ** (ueq', S_Trans s1 st1 st1', S_Trans s2 st2' st2)))`
```

`hyp1` has type `StSubtype s u` and `ueq` has type `u = StTApp s1 s2`. I would like a term `hyp1'`
with type `StSubtype s (StTApp s1 s2)`.

For this, I tried `rewrite ueq in hyp1`, which gives an error:

```
Error: While processing right hand side of theorem1. Rewriting
by u = StTApp s1 s2 did not change
type ?_ [locals in scope: u, t2, t1, hyp2, s, hyp1, s1, s2, ueq, st1, st2].
```

If I write a type annotation for `hyp1'`, `hyp1' : StSubtype s (StTApp s1 s2)`, it gives a similar error:

````
Error: While processing right hand side of theorem1. While processing right hand
side of $resolved2797,hyp1'. Rewriting by u = StTApp s1 s2 did not change
type StSubtype s (StTApp s1 s2).```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rewrite cong (StSubtype s) (sym ueq) in hyp1`

**What's `sym`?**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67050610/5986907). In brief, `rewrite` needs `StTApp s1 s2 = u` not `u = StTApp s1 s2`. `sym` flips the equality.

**What's `cong`?**

`rewrite a = b in c` changes the whole of the type of `c` from `b` to `a`. What you want is to turn `StSubtype s u` into `StSubtype s (StTApp s1 s2)`. You only have `StTApp s1 s2 = u` (after using `sym`), but need `StSubtype s (StTApp s1 s2) = StSubtype s u`. With

```
cong : (0 f : t -> u) -> (0 p : a = b) -> f a = f b
```

you can add the `StSubtype s`.

Comment: Your suggestion `rewrite cong (StSubtype s) ueq in hyp1` had the same error, but thanks to your explanation of `cong`, I could figure out the correct expression:
`hyp1' = replace {p = id} (cong (StSubtype s) ueq) hyp1`. Thank you @joel !

Comment: @HenriqueGuerra you also need `sym` for `rewrite`, which flips the equality, see my edit